# Removing misspelled items in the pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following dataset is a minor representation of an example of the problem I am facing:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Tom', 'Joseph', 'John'], 'id_product': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        'product_name': ["candy", "candy", "cookie", "coockie", "pepsi"],  'qtd_purchase': [1, 2, 4, 2, 2]}
```

the pandas form:

[image]

The problem is that, for example, if we look at the unique values ​​of each column we will find the following error:

```
for col in data.columns:
    if not 'no' in col and not 'code' in col and not 'id' in col:
        un_n = data[col].nunique()
        print(f'n of unique {col}: {un_n}')
```

n of unique Name: 3

n of unique product_name: 4

n of unique qtd_purchase: 3

the id_product should have the same number of product_name. But because of a typo mistake, we have items with the same code and different names. For example, "cookie" and "cookie".

I was able to find these items using the following code:

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = None
data.groupby(['id_product', 'product_name']).count()['qtd_purchase']
```

[image]

For that scale, this code solves just fine. But in my real problem, I have 21000 unique id_products and 23000 product_name. It becomes impossible to identify them using the code above. Would there be any way to just print the values ​​that are badly written?

For example, the answer would look like this:

[image]

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: So the `id` is always right, just in some cases the `product_name` has the wrong value?

Comment: Yes, I want to clean the names that came out incorrectly, but first I need to identify them, using the id.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach.

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Tom', 'Joseph', 'John'], 'id_product': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        'product_name': ["candy", "candy", "cookie", "coockie", "pepsi"],  'qtd_purchase': [1, 2, 4, 2, 2]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.loc[:,['id_product','product_name']].groupby(
    'id_product').filter(
    lambda g:any(g.nunique()>1)))
```

Result:

```
   id_product product_name
2           2       cookie
3           2      coockie
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `groupby` on the `id_product` column and then count the values of each product:

```py
df.groupby("id_product").product_name.value_counts()
```

For your example, this will return:

```py
id_product  product_name
1           candy           2
2           coockie         1
            cookie          1
3           pepsi           1
```

This could help you to learn more about your data. If we assume that the misspellings happen only occasionally, you can get the most common spelling for each id with [`mode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html). Let's add another purchase...

```py
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Tom', 'Joseph', 'John', "Cookie monster"], 
       'id_product': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2],
       'product_name': ["candy", "candy", "cookie", "coockie", "pepsi", "cookie"],  
       'qtd_purchase': [1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 42]}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head(6)
```

gives

```py
             Name  id_product product_name  qtd_purchase
0             Tom           1        candy             1
1          Joseph           1        candy             2
2             Tom           2       cookie             4
3          Joseph           2      coockie             2
4            John           3        pepsi             2
5  Cookie monster           2       cookie            42
```

and then:

```py
>>> df.groupby("id_product").product_name.apply(pd.Series.mode)
id_product   
1           0     candy
2           0    cookie
3           0     pepsi
Name: product_name, dtype: object
```